# Eclipse error: Unbound classpath container

Tags: eclipse, java

I recieved two error messages after I made my project:

1. The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved.
2. Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [OSGi/Minimum-1.2]' in project 'method_test'

I think that if I figure out the second error, the first one will go away. However, I am running eclipse Juno on a 10.5.8 Mac, and I cannot install the necessary JRE from the Oracle website, as they do not it compatible for Mac.

Comment: Edit the JRE System Library path to the path which is relevant for your system .

Answer (score 31):

1. Right click on the project
2. Open Properties
3. Select Java Build Path
4. Select the JRE System Library under the Libraries tab .
5. Click on Edit .
6. Click on Alternate JRE .
7. If Alternate JRE present , then Select it and hit Finish .
8. If not present , then click on Installed JREs which opens a pop up.
9. Click on Add .
10. Select Standard VM and Click Next.
11. Select the JRE Home , Navigate to JDK root and select that .
12. Click on Finish .
13. Select that in installed JREs.

Here is the link to  [JDK Mac Install](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html)

Comment: When I select the library and press edit, it is unresponsive.

Comment: Select the JRE System Library  under the Libraries tab . I guess you are running out of system memory and hence it hangs . Have patience !

Comment: JDK 7 is incompatible with my 10.5.8 mac. Also, I still have 67.7 gigabites of space left on my computer.